# php - return multiple values to from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, junction-table

I'm dealing with a junction table for a many to many relationship between products and categories. With this particular function I'm attempting to take in a product_ID variable and get all associated category names in an array. However, with the current setup I'm only getting one category per product ID when I know several have 2. Any thoughts? Also anyone know of a good simple solution to more visually keeping track of M2M relationships in mysql?

```
    //INPUT PRODUCT ID, GET ASSOCIATED CATEGORIES
    function productcat($pid) {
        global $sql;
        $query = "SELECT * FROM Product_Category WHERE Product_ID = '$pid'";
        $result = mysqli_query($sql, $query);
        $catidarray = array();
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                array_push($catidarray, $row['Category_ID']);
        }

        foreach($catidarray as $i) {
            $query = "SELECT * FROM Categories WHERE Category_ID = '$i'";
            $result = mysqli_query($sql, $query);
            $namearray = array();
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                array_push($namearray, $row['Name']);
            }

        }

        return $namearray;
    }
```

Comment: you have table **product** and table **category** as many to many? then how many tables does it comprise in your database in relation to those tables?

Comment: can you also show the some table structure?

Comment: I'm pretty new to both php and mysql.  But my table setup is pretty simple I have: 

Categories: with Category_ID and several other fields
Products: with Product_ID and several other fields
Product_Category (Junction Table) with Product_Category_ID, and Product_ID/Category_ID indexing those fields in the respective Product and Category tables

Comment: your `Product_Category_ID` is auto increment?

Comment: That's correct, all main ID tags of the tables are AI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is something wrong with your function.

In your second foreach, you put the variable **$namearray** inside the loop which on every run resets its value to empty array **$namearray = array();**. Just put that outside the foreach:

```
//--> put it here
$namearray = array();
foreach($catidarray as $i) {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM Categories WHERE Category_ID = '$i'";
    $result = mysqli_query($sql, $query);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        array_push($namearray, $row['Name']);
    }
}
```

And, I just want to make some suggestions on your function. Since you have the `junction table`, you don't really need to have a separate query for `product` and `category` in order to get your desired values from those tables.

Just do the [**INNER JOIN**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706437/whats-the-difference-between-inner-join-left-join-right-join-and-full-join) to maximize the use of your table relations.

Use your junction table `Product_Category` because that's the real purpose why created that.

```
SELECT *
FROM Product_Category AS a
INNER JOIN Category AS b
ON a.Category_ID = b.Category_ID
WHERE Product_ID = $pid
```

In your function, you may try this: havent tested but hope this will give you idea.

```
//INPUT PRODUCT ID, GET ASSOCIATED CATEGORIES
function productcat($pid) {
    global $sql;
    $query = "SELECT *
              FROM Product_Category as a
              INNER JOIN Category as b
              ON a.Category_ID = b.Category_ID
              WHERE Product_ID = {$pid}";
    $result = mysqli_query($sql, $query);
    $namearray = array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            array_push($catidarray, $row['Name']);
    }
    return $namearray;
}
```

Then that's it :)

And by the way, in the latest version of php, **mysql_** functions are already deprecated. Much better if you will be going to use [**PDO**](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info) or [MySQLi](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/mysqli/info).
Check this also: [PDO vs. MySQLi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13569/mysqli-or-pdo-what-are-the-pros-and-cons)